# Delete elements from a list with filter in Angular2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Through Angular 2, I show an array through a list element, which has next to each element a button named Remove, it is actioned through a  function which uses .filter() for deleting the respective element. But after clicking this button, and try to add elements to the array, than the array restores to it's old self, and adds the new element, but the list element does not modifies.

Here I'll attach the part from the component, service and HTML which array responsible for removing the item

> The component fragment

```
    remove(item: List) {
    this.list = this.listService.remover(this.list, item);
    localStorage.setItem('lists', JSON.stringify(this.list));
}
```

> The service fragment

```
    remover(listArray: List[], list: List) {
    const listArray1 = listArray.filter(item => item.id !== list.id);
    return listArray1;
}
```

> The HTML (Template) fragment

```
<div>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
      <!-- {{checkItem(item)}} -->
      <div *ngIf="checkItem(item)">
        <input type="checkbox" class="stat" (click)="status(item)" [(checked)]="item.status" />
        <span class="task">{{item.task}}</span>
        <button class="listBtn" (click)="edit(item)">EDIT</button>
        <button class="listBtn" (click)="remove(item)">REMOVE</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you check in the console for local storage? Is element really getting removed?

Comment: Yes it gets removed, but after i insert a new element, than the local storage restores to the sate before removing and adds the new element

Comment: code for insertion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`html`

```
<div>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index;">
      <!-- {{checkItem(item)}} -->
      <div *ngIf="checkItem(item)">
        <input type="checkbox" class="stat" (click)="status(item)" [(checked)]="item.status" />
        <span class="task">{{item.task}}</span>
        <button class="listBtn" (click)="edit(item)">EDIT</button>
        <button class="listBtn" (click)="remove(item, i)">REMOVE</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
```

`component`

```
remove(item: List, index) {
    this.list.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('lists', JSON.stringify(this.list));
}
```

no any services needed